# When '/' is used for url of a parent state two slashes appear in url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

**Update:**
My assumption was [wrong](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2736). I expected that urls represent components of the path with corresponding combination in a way how final path is usually produced. But urls are just concatenated, nothing more.

I have the following states:

```
.state('banksList',
{
    url: '/',
    ...
})
.state('banksList.bank',
{
    url: '/bank/{bankId}',
    ...             
})
.state('banksList.bank.branch',
{
    url: '/branch/{branchId}',
    ...
})
```

After transition to `banksList.bank` browser shows `http://bla-bla//bank/1`, and base tag points to `http://bla-bla/`.

It looks like urls are just concatenated. Do I need to enable some mode or what?

Comment: I *think* you can either use an empty string for the root state, or maybe don't start the second one with a slash.

Comment: @DanielSchaffer Yes, I tried it, and it works...Yet somewhat ugly solution. =)

Answer (score 1):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kr6lDjQRY1YISnflZLkh?p=preview)

To keep your expectations working, you can just use magical sign **`^`**. That is effectively saying to UI-Router: "restart url definition, do not use parent part"

```
.state('banksList',
{
    url: '/',
    ...
})
.state('banksList.bank',
{
    url: '^/bank/{bankId}',
    ...             
})
.state('banksList.bank.branch',
{
    url: '/branch/{branchId}',
    ...
})
```

See:

#### [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol '^'.
...

So, as the example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kr6lDjQRY1YISnflZLkh?p=preview) shows, these links will work as expected

```
<a href="#/">
<a href="#/bank/B1">
<a href="#/bank/B2">
<a href="#/bank/B1/branch/A1">
<a href="#/bank/B2/branch/A22">

<a ui-sref="banksList">
<a ui-sref="banksList.bank({bankId: 'X1'})">
<a ui-sref="banksList.bank({bankId: 'X2'})">
<a ui-sref="banksList.bank.branch({bankId: 'X1', branchId: 'Y1'})">
<a ui-sref="banksList.bank.branch({bankId: 'X2', branchId: 'Y22'})">
```

Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kr6lDjQRY1YISnflZLkh?p=preview)

Comment: No, I want parent part to present. I simply see no difference between '/' and '/list'. In the latter case concatenation gives expected url '/list/bank/{bankId}' Thoug I have not checked what happens with '/list/' as a url of parent state, I believe that mere concatenation is a wrong behavior.

Comment: NO? I am not sure if I get it? this is the way how to.. Do you have some plunker to show that it is not working? I can assist to you to make it as you want...

Comment: May be I didn't get you, but the text under link you gave me states 'The urls were not combined because ^ was used.' I do want them to be combined. However 'combined' does not mean 'simply concatenated without processing', or does it? I want parent url to be combined with child state url. I expect that `combine('/','/bank/{bankId}')` should yield '/bank/{bankId}', and `combine('/list','/bank/{bankId}')`should yield '/list/bank/{bankId}'.

Comment: I added a plunker for you, hope now you will see how to.. good luck

Answer (score 0):

An empty string `url` in your `banksList` state works:

```
.state('banksList', {
  url: '',
  ...
})
.state('banksList.bank', {
  url: '/bank/{bankId}',
  ...
})
.state('banksList.bank.branch', {
  url: '/branch/{branchId}',
  ...
})
```