# Link to a child state with a param using ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

**States**

```
.state('event.detail', {
    url: '/:id',
    views: {
        'event-detail': {
            controller: EventDetail,
            templateUrl: ...
        }
    }
})
.state('event.detail.info', {
    url: '/info',
    views: {
        'event-info': {
            templateUrl: ...
        }
    }
})
.state('event.detail.map', {
    url: '/map',
    views: {
        'event-map': {
            templateUrl: ...
        }
    }
})
```

**ui-sref**

```
<a ui-sref="event.detail({id: event.id}).map">Map</a>
```

This gives me an `Invalid state ref` error.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? event.detail.map doesnt accept params, hence the error.

Comment: I want to be able to show a few different tabs of detail for each event. eg. `/event/1/info`, `/event/1/map`, `/event/2/info`, `/event/2/map`, etc. and be able to link straight to `/map` from `/event`

Comment: How about `event/map/1`, `event/info/2` etc. and pass a param to the child state just like the parent state?

Comment: I'll give that a try, just seems like the other way would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there... just first is the state **name**, then is the parameters object passed

```
// instead of this
<a ui-sref="event.detail({id: event.id}).map">Map</a>
// create this
<a ui-sref="event.detail.map({id: event.id})">Map</a>
```

There is *somehow similar* [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37129851/1679310), where I created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kr6lDjQRY1YISnflZLkh?p=preview), which should show that all in action *(even with parent having params and child has its own)*

Comment: Thanks, that worked for changing to the right URL but now my controller isn't running for some reason. I've updated the Q with a bit more info.

Comment: I cannot see any issues, controller should be invoked ... Could you create a simple plunker or adjust mine? I am ready to assist...

Comment: I've simplified it from my version a bit but this should be similar enough to what I've got. http://plnkr.co/edit/5tnEUndo6LMYigPXBoUX

Comment: That example doesn't seem to have the same problem I'm having. Not sure what's going on. I'll mark your answer and correct, thanks for your help.